# How to use a path parameter in wicket login page

Tags: java, authentication, wicket

I have a protected wicket page mounted with a path parameter, such as this:

```
class MyApp extends AuthenticatedWebApplication {
  @Override protected void init() {
    mountPage("/login/${site}", MyLoginPage.class);
    mountPage("/admin/${site}", MyAdminPage.class);
  }
  @Override protected Class<? extends WebPage> getSignInPageClass() {
    return MyLoginPage.class;
} }

@AuthorizeInstantiation("ADMIN")
class MyAdminPage extends WebPage { ... }
```

I'd like to keep this "site" parameter in the login page (I need this parameter in the login process). But apparently the default `AuthenticatedWebApplication::onUnauthorizedInstantiation` interceptor redirect to the login page without any parameters, so when accessing the admin page I get redirected to the login page with a NULL site...

How can I re-use the "site" parameter in the login page? I can eventually re-write my own AuthenticatedWebApplication to write a specific onUnauthorizedInstantiation interceptor, but there could be a simpler way to do that.

One requirement is to keep the login page bookmarkable, so the "site" parameter should be part of the URL (as a path parameter).

Comment: Have you had a look at the continueToOriginalDestination-method already (http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#continueToOriginalDestination%28%29)? I would just mount my (secured) pages and if you are not logged-in when you call them, you will get redirected to the login-page and from there on to the original site. Without the hassle of passing the URL as a parameter.

Comment: The problem is passing the "site" page parameter of the original page to the login page itself, not to the original one. Redirection to the original page is not an issue.

Comment: But why do you need the "site"-parameter in your Login-page?

Comment: Because I need the site for the login process, the same login can be used several times for different sites. I do not want the user to select the site before login, and it has to be bookmarkable.

Comment: What about storing the site-parameter in a session (ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Session.html)?

Comment: Well, I initially tried that, by using a redirect dummy page storing the site in the session, but this won't work when the session expire (the user have to go back to the login page).

Comment: Did you tried to overwrite restartResponseAtSignInPage()?

Answer (score 2):

Override method restartResponseAtSignInPage to invoke your login page and make a parameter that is specific for your site. I give you an example with whole context path because I do not exactly know what you use to identify the site.

```
class MyApp extends AuthenticatedWebApplication {

    @Override protected void init() {
        super.init();
        mountPage("/login/${site}", MyLoginPage.class);
        mountPage("/admin/${site}", MyAdminPage.class);
    }

    @Override   
    public void restartResponseAtSignInPage() {
        // contextPath is just an example, implement here anything 
        // you use to identify the page or site
        String contextPath = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContextPath();
        throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(new MyLoginPage(new PageParameters().add("site", contextPath)));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

**NOTE1:** If you has to continue with any of parameters from the original request, see how to extract parameters from request cycle

```
IRequestParameters requestParameters = RequestCycle.get().getRequestParameters();
```

**NOTE2:** You can really override full functionality of the original AuthenticatedWebApplication that is a bit complicated because of final methods. Probably you have to modify the following code to exactly extract your site parameter that I do not know exactly.

```
class MyApp extends AuthenticatedWebApplication {

@Override 
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    mount("/login/${site}", MyLoginPage.class);
    mountPage("/admin/${site}", MyAdminPage.class);
    getSecuritySettings().setUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener(new IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onUnauthorizedInstantiation(Component component) {
            MyApp.this.onMyUnauthorizedInstantiation(Component component);

        }
    });
}

public void onMyUnauthorizedInstantiation(final Component component) {
    if (component instanceof Page)
    {
        if (!AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession.get().isSignedIn())
        {
            // Redirect to intercept page to let the user sign in
            restartResponseAtSignInPage((Page)component);
        }
        else
        {
            onUnauthorizedPage((Page)component);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The component was not a page, so throw an exception
        throw new UnauthorizedInstantiationException(component.getClass());
    }
}


@Override   
public void restartResponseAtSignInPage(Page page) {
    // contextPath is just an example, implement here anything 
    // you use to identify the page or site
    throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(new MyLoginPage(new PageParameters().add("site", page.getPageParameters().get("site").toString("defaultValue"))));
}

}
```

Comment: I already tried this before, but I'd like to get the original page parameters from the request to get the correct site. I could use a workaround by manually parsing the client URL of the request, but this is error-prone as it rely on assumptions on the way pages are mounted. I think I could theoretically access the page parameters as I can see them somewhere upward in the stacktrace when setting a breakpoint in this method.